# QLineEdit hover-over Signal - when mouse is over the QlineEdit

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4, mouseover, signals-slots, qlineedit

I have a `QLineEdit`, and I need to know if there is a signal which can track mouse hover over that `QLineEdit`, and once mouse is over that `QLineEdit` it emits a signal.

I have seen the documents, and found we have the following signals:

> cursorPositionChanged ( int old, int new )
>   editingFinished ()
>   returnPressed ()
>   selectionChanged ()
>   textChanged ( const QString & text )
>   textEdited ( const QString & text )

However, none of this is exactly for hover-over. Can you suggest if this can be done by any other way in PyQt4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no built-in mouse-hover signal for a QLineEdit.

However, it is quite easy to achieve something similar by installing an [event-filter](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#eventFilter). This technique will work for any type of widget, and the only other thing you might need to do is to [set mouse tracking](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#mouseTracking-prop) (although this seems to be switched on by default for QLineEdit).

The demo script below show how to track various mouse movement events:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.edit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        self.edit.installEventFilter(self)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.edit)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if source is self.edit:
            if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseMove:
                pos = event.globalPos()
                print('pos: %d, %d' % (pos.x(), pos.y()))
            elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Enter:
                print('ENTER')
            elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Leave:
                print('LEAVE')
        return QtGui.QWidget.eventFilter(self, source, event)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(500, 300, 300, 100)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `enterEvent`, `leaveEvent`, enterEvent is triggered when mouse enters the widget and leave event is triggered when the mouse leaves the widget. These events are in the `QWidget` class, `QLineEdit` inherits `QWidget`, so you can use these events in `QLineEdit`. I you don't see these events in `QLineEdit`'s documentation, click on the link *List of all members, including inherited members* at the top of the page.